# Escape TabStop within a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm building a email client in c# that allows users to send HTML emails. I have some general formatting capabilities including the option to insert bulleted and numbered lists. I want to allow users to tab through the controls, but also use the tab key to indent the bullets or numbers in their list. Is there a way to escape TabStop within a certain control, a webBrowser control in particular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David sparked the idea, but I'd like to give a little more detail. I used mshtml to actually insert the indent and outdent. Just that still moved to the next control, so adding `e.IsInputKey = true` actually kept the cursor in the webBrowser control so the user can continue typing.

```
  private void webBrowser_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.KeyData == Keys.Tab)
     {
        webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Indent", false, null);
        e.IsInputKey = true;    //prevents going to next control
     }
     else if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Tab))
     {
        webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Outdent", false, null);
        e.IsInputKey = true;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a multiline TextBox you can use the [AcceptsTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx) property.

For a WebBrowser control I think you have to use the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase.keypress.aspx) event and insert a tab character `\t` yourself.